# Recover init.vim from inside a certain session

Tags: neovim, init.vim

I accidentally deleted my `init.vim` using a `rm -rf` command.

I know that this kind of stuff is irreversible, but luckily I've kept a terminal running neovim open before I've done this madness.
Is there any way to restore or read the loaded `init.vim` file from inside the session? Maybe there is a temporary file created each session?

Comment: The file is read into memory and stored in a form nothing like the file, I'm sure. The closest you'd probably get is to dump settings with commands like `:set`, `:com`, `:map` (and, yes, `:mksess` with all relevant options enabled) and try to piece everything back together. Whether you do that or not start regularly backing up your system, for the love of god. ;)

Comment: there is a mkrc or mkexrc or something that gets close? Also, version control those dotfiles :)

Comment: I've ended up giving up and started a new init.vim. From now on, git is my best friend :P

Answer (score 1):

The command you were looking for is `:mkvimrc`, which dumps a lot of settings.

It may or may not get everything you lost, depending on how you configure your system (*e.g.*, I’m not sure what’s picked up from ftplugins). You’ll certainly want to edit the results.